# How can I calculate OEIS A144311 efficiently?

Tags: sequences-and-series, mathematica, twin-primes, oeis

I'm looking for a way to calculate [OEIS A144311](https://oeis.org/A144311) efficiently.

In one sense or another, this series considers the number between "relative" twin primes. What do I mean by this?

Well, the number $77$ is relatively prime to {$2,3,5$} even tho it's not actually prime. We're looking for relative twin primes to this set tho: consecutive odds relatively prime to {$2,3,5$}. For instance, $(77,79)$ would be an example of such. Neither number is divisible by {$2,3,5$}.

$78$ then is the number between these. The next smallest number between a similarly relative twin prime pair would be $90$. $(89,91)$ is the next relative (and real) twin prime pair. That gives us a relative twin prime gap of 12 (being $90-78$), and 11 fails between successes. The question is, what is the largest possible twin prime gap relative to just {$2,3,5$}? This so happens to be it. 11 is the max fails for {$2,3,5$}. The series says that 29 is the max fails for {$2,3,5,7$}, and 41 for {$2,3,5,7,11$}, the first 5 primes.

Now that we've well defined these, what would be the best way to calculate them? Also, what is the 17th number in this series? All methods I've used to try to calculate these have resulted in numbers beyond what can be handled well even in something like Mathematica even by the 10th number in the series.

Comment: +1, nice question. I removed the [tag:generating-functions] tag. When in doubt, please avail yourself of the tag summaries in selecting tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see basically two approaches, and a hybrid of them that's more efficient than either.

First, you could try out all combinations of residues other than $-1,1$ that the primes could have at the one end of the sequence, and then see how far you get in each case. The number of combinations would be

$$
\prod_{i=3}^n(p_i-2)\;,
$$

i.e. $3\cdot5\cdot9\cdot11\cdot15\cdot17\cdot21\cdot27\cdot29\cdot35\cdot39\cdot41\cdot45\cdot51\cdot57\approx4.6\cdot10^{19}$ to reach $p_{17}$, so this is not feasible.

Second, you could start out without fixing residues for the primes and start moving to the right, and whenever you hit a slot that's not covered yet, you pick a prime whose residue hasn't been fixed yet and try the two possible residues to cover the slot. That would require trying out $2^nn!$ different choices, or $2^{17}\cdot17!\approx4.7\cdot10^{19}$ to reach $p_{17}$, funny enough almost the same number, so this isn't feasible, either.

But note that the first approach is costly for large primes and the second approach is costly for many primes, so we can advantageously combine them by adopting the first approach for the small primes and the second approach for the large primes. That is, we try out all combinations of residues for the primes up to, say, $p_7=17$, and then we move right and fix one of the remaining residues whenever we hit an uncovered slot. To reach $p_{17}$, this requires trying out

$$
3\cdot5\cdot9\cdot11\cdot15\cdot2^{10}\cdot10!\approx8\cdot10^{13}
$$

combinations, a whole lot better and within reach of our electronic friends.

[Here's java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/61860c6d85853d39f6b470ec0c42e290) that applies this approach. I used it to replicate the sequence up to $p_{14}$, which took $1000$ seconds on my MacBook Pro, so you can expect to find the result for $p_{17}$ in about $5760000$ seconds, or about two months. It's probably not a coincidence that this is on the boundary of what's feasible with today's computers; the calculation of the values up to $p_{16}$ (which would take about $2$ days this way) dates from $2009$, and I suspect that they were calculated in precisely this manner.

Comment: Sorry I'm just getting back to this. This is awesome! Is there a way to run this via Mathematica? I don't know Java, but have Mathematica on my pi and am struggling to calculate past the 10th in less than a day.

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: I'm sure it can be done, but I don't have Mathematica myself. I could implement it in Sage, in case that helps.

Comment: Sure actually. I simply don't understand java enough to get what's going on, so some other math software would be great. I'll have to learn how to use sage some, but I'd imagine that'd be closer to Mathematica than Java. Don't waste too much time through if it'll take too long. Thanks!

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: [Here's a Sage version](https://gist.github.com/joriki/9ea6aad5ea010ca8eaa95917b7c4e8cf). It's significantly slower than the Java version; I'm not as experienced in Python so there may be a lot of room for making it more efficient. But it does give the right answers after a while :-)

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: I just figured out how to make SageMathCloud files public, so here it is directly: https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/b56c609c-b576-4e49-b960-3b923ba9b816/files/A144311.sagews. You can make a copy of it there to run it yourself.

Comment: Thanks again Joriki! I've been monkeying with this and have messed a lot with sage, and trying to get it. I know I keep bothering you, but I wonder if you might clarify a few things for me just on the math side of things so I can continue trying to write a version in mathematica: If I understand your First Approach, for $p_3=5$ you mean finding all numbers neither 1 nor -1 mod 2, 3, and 5 up to 30. This list would include {$12,18,30$}. Since the biggest difference of these is 12, the answer is 12-1=11. Is that a correct assessment? How would I similarly build a list for your Second Approach?

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: I don't mean finding all such numbers in the form of a list -- that list couldn't be held in memory. I mean iterating over them and in each case finding the distance to the next one. Both approaches are based on choosing residues at the left-hand "failure" of a sequence and traversing the sequence to find the distance to the right-hand "failure"; the difference is just that in the first approach all residues are chosen at the beginning, whereas in the second approach they're chosen as you go along the sequence and need new primes to defer the right-hand "failure".

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting it better although I'm still not grasping it without an explicit example. So by sequence, you mean for instance 18 to 30. 19 is our first failure. It is {$1,1,4$} mod {$2,3,5$} respectively. Your first approach says to choose residues at the beginning. Does this mean recognizing failures at any residues of {$1,1,1$} or {$1,2,4$}, thus continuing to count up from 19 until something without one of those residues is hit (30 which is {$0,0,0$})? Thanks for your patience with my failure to grasp this so far!

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: No, here $18$ would be the left-hand failure, with residues $(0,0,3)$. Starting with those residues, we'd find that as we increase each of them by $1$ in each step, always one of them is $\pm1$ until we reach $30$, the second failure, with residues $(0,0,0)$. That's the first approach. In the second approach, we start with unknown residues $(*,*,*)$ at the first failure, $x$ then try to make a step and find that we don't yet have a prime that covers $x+1$, so we choose one, trying all three possibilities. E.g., when we try out using $5$ to cover $x+1$, ...

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: ..., we can fix $x\bmod 5$ either as $0$ or as $3$, since these are the two values that will yield $x+1\equiv\pm1\bmod5$. Say we choose $x\equiv3\bmod5$; we now have $(*,*,3)$, and then we take the next step and find again that $x+2$ isn't covered yet; we've used up $5$, so we can now choose whether to use $2$ or $3$. If e.g. we now use $3$ we can't choose $x+2\equiv+1\bmod3$, since that would yield $x\equiv-1\bmod3$, which can't be since $x$ is a failure. So in this case only the option $x+2\equiv-1\bmod3$ is pursued, with residues $(*,0,3)$ now fixed. And so on.

Comment: Got it, so combining your 2 approaches: starting at failure 30 I fix residues $(0,0,0,2,8,4,13)$ so that I’m checking residues for primes up to $p_7=17$. 31 has three 1’s in its residue set, so I continue. 32 is $(0,2,…)$ so its -1 mod 3, thus I continue again. I’ll continue to get hits until 42 which is $(0,0,2,0,9,3,8)$. Here I’m a little lost. I’d now use the 2nd approach, right? We’ll suppose I’m testing up to $p_{10}=29$. I’ll try out using 29 to cover $x+12$. I can fix $x \pmod {29}$ as either 16 or 18 since these are the two values that will yield $x+12 \equiv +-1 \pmod {29}$. ...

Comment: Say I choose 16. Do I now continue with the 1st approach again until no hits (checking also 29 now, starting at a residue of 16?) then use the 2nd approach again, choosing 23 to cover another? When I’ve used 19 to cover, does that mean I’m done? I’m just not able to make this last part click.

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: It sounds like you got most of it right now, but two things that may be causing the problem at the end: a) I don't think of it as starting at $30$. In the hybrid, you start at $x$, like in the second approach, but you fix the residues of $x$ up to $p_7=17$ up front. So if you like, you can think of it as starting at $30+x$, where $x$ is some multiple of $\prod_{i=1}^7p_i$; but I just think of it as $x$ with $7$ residues fixed.

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: b) It sounds as if you're trying the larger primes in a fixed order, from $p_10$ to $p_8$. The idea is to try them in all possible orders, with all possible choices of $\pm1$. When you've tried something, say $+1$ for $p_{10}$, then $+1$ for $p_9$, then $+1$ for $p_8$, you keep going along the sequence until you hit the next failure; since you have no primes left to cover it, you can't go any further, so you update the maximum, backtrack and try $-1$ for $p_8$ at the point where you tried $+1$ before. Once you're done trying that, you backtrack even further ...

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: ... to the point where you tried $+1$ for $p_9$ and try $-1$ for $p_9$ instead at that point. That leads to some more recursion for the two choices $\pm1$ for $p_8$ again, and then when you backtrack after that you now try $p_8$ before $p_9$, again all $4$ combinations of $\pm1$. The code uses recursion to make the backtracking easy; at each decision, you just make one recursive call for each of the options, and when the call returns you're back where you were, ready to try the next option. ("$p_10$" above was meant to be "$p_{10}$"; too late to edit now. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I forget the braces often myself. :-) Just about everything makes sense now! Thanks for all your help! One more question: after you've done all possible combinations starting at the first uncovered spot, would you then also have to try leaving the first spot uncovered, starting at the 2nd uncovered, and completing all combinations there? Then leave the first 2 uncovered and start at the third? Thanks again for **ALL** your help. Wish I could up-vote multiple times. =)

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you talking about the first uncovered spot that we encounter along the sequence? We can't leave that uncovered; then we wouldn't have a covered sequence. If you leave it uncovered and don't count the stretch before it towards the sequence, then you've just restarted the process with a new failure point; but we're already trying all possibilities for the left-hand failure point, so there's nothing new to be gained by allowing for a new one. But I may have misunderstood what you wrote.

Comment: I guess an easier way of saying it would be: do we begin the process of testing combinations of the remaining primes only at the first position left uncovered by the the 1st approach (ie 30) or do we again begin that process with a sequence starting at 42?

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: I think I see what you mean now. You need to try all possible combinations of residues of the "small" primes at $x$. If I understand correctly, you're summarising those residues in a single residue of $x$ modulo the product of the small primes. Then yes, you need to try all possible values for that residue: $0,30,42,\ldots$. (I'm not sure why you're calling $30$ the first of them; the least of them is $0$.)

Comment: That all makes sense now! Thanks! I think I see now how I can go about writing this in mathematica. You've been awesome! Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: Great. Let me know how it goes :-) I doubt it will be faster than in Java -- so you'll probably need a bit of patience to continue the OEIS entry :-)

Comment: Probably, although I think I see a way to run parts of the code in parallel, which I don't think the java code did. So if I could match the speed of the java code (unlikely), 4 cores could give 4x speed. We'll see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40299/discussion-between-elem-teach-w-bach-n-math-ed-and-joriki).

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: I was sleeping when you sent that chat invitation. I'm on Central European Time. I should be online most of the evening in case you still want to chat.

Comment: Sorry, looks like we're 8 hours apart. I'm in US Mountain Time. I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Taking @joriki's approach, I've now written a version that runs in Mathematica. I'm including now only the latest and just previous revisions to keep this from getting lengthy. The last revision saw a 5x speedup do to the number between twin primes being divisible by 6, and (in the case of my code) the number $2$ and $4$ more than the twins respectively being $\equiv 3 \pmod 6$. Here's the final:

You can run this for free by going to [lab.wolframcloud.com/app](https://lab.wolframcloud.com/app/) and creating a free account.

```
list3[a_, b_, c_] := Union[
  Range[ChineseRemainder[{3, a}, {6, Prime[c]}], b, 6*Prime[c]],
  Range[ChineseRemainder[{3, a + 2}, {6, Prime[c]}], b, 6*Prime[c]]]

tpgaps7[x_, z_] := Module[{plist, tplist, tuples, k, mgap}, 
  plist = Times @@ Table[Prime[y], {y, 1, x}];
  tplist = Complement[Range[3, plist, 6], Flatten[Table[Union[
    Range[2, plist, Prime[n]], 
    Range[4, plist, Prime[n]]], {n, 3, x}]]];
  tuples = Tuples[Table[Table[{a, plist, c}, {a, 0, Prime[c - 1]}], {c, x + 1, z}]];
  k = Length[tuples];
  mgap = AbsoluteTiming[Max[(*Parallel*)Table[Max[Differences@Complement[
    tplist, Flatten[Union @@ Apply[list3, Part[tuples, j], {1}]]]],
    {j, 1, k}]] - 1];
  {mgap}]

Do[Print[tpgaps7[7, i]], {i, 7, 10}]

(*Times when running in Parallel on my Rasp Pi*)
{{0.064885,7,107}}
{{0.097869,8,149}}
{{1.26251,9,203}}
{{35.9214,10,257}}

(*Times for non-parallel online programming lab*)
{{0.003366,7,107}}
{{0.015974,8,149}}
{{0.498724,9,203}}
{{15.4054,10,257}}
```

***Previous DEBUGGED/OPTIMIZED VERSION***

```
list3[a_,b_,c_]:=Union[Range[a,b,Prime[c]],Range[a+2,b,Prime[c]]]

tpgaps6[x_,z_]:=Module[{plist,tplist,tuples,k,mgap},
  plist=Times@@Table[Prime[y],{y,1,x}];
  tplist=Complement[Range[3,plist,6],
    Flatten[Table[Union[
      Range[2,plist,Prime[n]],
      Range[4,plist,Prime[n]]],
    {n,3,x}]]];
  tuples=Tuples[Table[Table[{a,plist,c},{a,0,Prime[c-1]}],{c,x+1,z}]];
  k=Length[tuples];
  mgap=AbsoluteTiming[Max[ParallelTable[
    Max[Differences@Complement[tplist,
      Flatten[Union@@Apply[list3,Part[tuples,j],{1}]]]],{j,1,k}]]-1];
{z,mgap}]

Do[Print[AbsoluteTiming[tpgaps6[7,i]]],{i,7,10}]

(*Times when running in Parallel on my Rasp Pi*)
{0.554687,{7,{0.053122,107}}}
{0.659064,{8,{0.164598,149}}}
{5.49219,{9,{5.00954,203}}}
{173.238,{10,{172.752,257}}}

(*Times for non-parallel online programming lab*)
{0.078032,{7,{0.00339,107}}}
{0.105818,{8,{0.035588,149}}}
{1.45627,{9,{1.38502,203}}}
{48.1555,{10,{48.0839,257}}}
```

Comment: But $227$ and $317$ are both off by $30$?

Comment: @joriki Yeah, I did catch that as well, but was headed to bed. I think I may know why. Need to do some testing to make sure tho.

Comment: @joriki Found the error... Part of the code read "c" instead of Prime[c]. In essence, when what was needed was a list of numbers from 1 to prime 10 (29), instead it was just calculating based off just 1-10... thus although the error is fixed, everything now takes about 3x as long. =(

Comment: @joriki Found about a 5x speedup on my code! Will be posting shortly!

Answer (score 2):

This can be considered as a kind of covering problem, which can be formulated as an integer linear programming problem.
Suppose you want to see if $A144311(n) \ge m$.
We ask to cover the set $S = \{1, \ldots, m\}$, where each prime $p$ of the first $n$ primes will cover those members of $S$ congruent to $a_p \pm 1 \mod p$ for some $a_p \in \{0, \ldots, p-1\}$.  Given such a covering, if $T$ is an integer $\equiv -a_p \mod p$ for each of these $p$, then $T+1, \ldots, T+m$ is a sequence of $m$ consecutive integers that satisfies the requirement (the existence of $T$ is guaranteed by the Chinese Remainder Theorem).

In the integer linear programming formulation, we have $0-1$ variables $x_{p,a}$ for each of our primes $p$ and $a = 0 \ldots p-1$, with the constraints

$$ \eqalign{\sum_p \sum_{a \equiv i \pm 1 \mod p} x_{p,a} &\ge 1 \ \text{for}\ i=1 \ldots m\cr
\sum_{a=0}^{p-1} x_{p,a} &= 1 \ \text{for each}\ p \cr
\text{all} & x_{p,a} \in \{0,1\}}$$

For $n = 12$, it took Cplex on my computer about 14 seconds to show that $m=527$ is feasible, and about 22 seconds to show that $m=528$ is infeasible.  However, I expect computing times to rise rather rapidly as $n$ increases, although maybe not as rapidly as for exhaustive search methods.

Another possibility is to attack this with a SAT solver.

Feasible solutions might be found using heuristic search methods such as tabu search or simulated annealing, providing lower bounds.  Proving upper bounds is likely to be more difficult.

Comment: So I'd imagine n=16 m=870 is beyond reasonable time limits?

Comment: Interesting -- we should compare times to see which method scales better. Times in seconds (on my MacBook Pro) for my solution are: $1,6,70,1000$ for $11\le n\le14$; they increase roughly as expected. Can you go up to $n=14$ or $15$ to compare?

Comment: For $n=14$, it took 56.8 seconds to show $m=617$ is feasible, but 892.5 seconds to show $m=618$ is infeasible.

Comment: That gives a factor of $\frac{1000\cdot22}{892.5\cdot6}\approx4$ better scaling from $n=12$ to $n=14$ than my method; so you might be able to reach $n=17$ in a slightly more reasonable time (also @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed).

Comment: By the way, a better command for "mod" used as a binary operator is `\bmod`, which doesn't produce the big space that's meant for the use of `\mod` at the end of equations.

Comment: This is definitely intriguing! Do you mind sharing your Cplex code? Or even better, writing a version for mathematica?